Fantasy episode with mermaid or other creature, strangling with her prehensile hair
I am looking for English/American movie or an episode from TV series, in which someone told a legend about a beautiful naked woman strangling on the beach/island with her hair. She was naked completely, but I watched it only as “memory” of storyteller. I watched something like that about 20 years ago, but I can’t recall the title and it could be from 80s or 90s.
Strangling with hair is not an uncommon feature in media, e.g., this essay called " The Devouring Woman and Her Serpentine Hair in Late-Pre-Raphaelitism".
I asked in Reddit and I checked TV tropes, but no results.
https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PrehensileHair

Why is this tagged "the mysterious island"? The book includes no mermaids, with prehensile hair or otherwise

@ArcanistLupus - Well, it has an island, and the island is mysterious?

@Adamant the tag is exclusively for the Jules Verne novel

Since OP doesn't know if it's a movie or a TV episode, it seems redundant tagging it with both
